# Questions tagged both [big-list] and [soft-question]

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have noticed that a [sizable fraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list+soft-question?sort=newest&pageSize=50) of posts tagged both [big-list] and [soft question] on this site have over ten upvotes. Moreover, another sizable fraction of those were posted by users under 500 rep and started off as non-community wiki. It seems possible that some of these questions are posted purely for the reputation, and frankly, I'm surprised that there aren't more of these posts. While there is nothing inherently wrong with that, a lot of these users have gained a large amount, if not a majority, of their reputation from that single post. Here's my suggestion: questions with both of these tags and more than a certain number of upvotes should automatically be made community wiki. For the number of upvotes, I would suggest ten. I have three reasons for this number. First, I think that new users can crave reputation for legitimate reasons, such as getting more privileges, and for new users, 50 reputation seems like a reasonable value from these questions. Second, these questions are important contributions to the community, so I think some reputation gain is certainly deserved. However, any more reputation gain would mean that people could just start churning out these questions and get excess undeserved reputation.

P.S. Please forgive me if I'm being [hypocritical.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798215/nuking-the-mosquito-ridiculously-complicated-ways-to-achieve-very-simple-resul)

Comment: I dislike this proposal for various reasons. I can elaborate if you want.

Comment: "It seems possible that some of these questions are posted purely for the reputation" - this seems very unlikely to me. Besides, many of these types of questions get closed, not exactly a reputation "booster"!

Comment: Keep in mind that recently the CW system went through a change, and now [**no posts** get automatically converted into CW](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/). So asking for a new automatic trigger is a non-starter.

Comment: @Arthur: Due to edits. After 30 answers the hammer strikes, as the recently asked obvious false theorems show.

Comment: @Asaf: I'm looking into this (or trying to). Grace Note announced [in](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947/214632) [several](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228951/214632) [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228940/214632) [answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228946/214632) that auto conversions simply no longer happen.

Comment: @Asaf: Upon some further investigation, a moderator _did_ convert that question to CW; it was not an automatic trigger, though a few automatic flags were raised.  (I don't know why the moderator isn't listed, however.)

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just flag the question and the mods will make it community wiki if it needs to be.  Whether the reputation gained during the time it takes us to get to your flag is undeserved or not, it certainly isn't significant enough to warrant making a system-side change to the software.